# why getting the error of NameError: name 'file' is not defined in python 3

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, nameerror

I'm wondering why I got the NameError: name 'file' is not defined in python 3 when calling a function?

```
def func(file):
    for file in os.listdir(cwd):
        if file.endswith('.html'):
                f = open(file, "r+")
                ....
                f = open(file, "w")
                f.write(text)
                f.close()

func(file)
```

and maybe another simple example:

```
def func(hello):
    print('Hello')

func(hello)
```

I also got the same error NameError: name 'hello' is not defined.
I don't quite understand why this syntax is not compatible with Python3?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Python should know what is hello? define hello then use it in the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't compatible with any version of Python. `hello` (or `file` or any other parameter name) is a name that's only usable within the function body.

When calling `func(hello)` Python will try and look-up the name `hello` in the *global scope* and fail because such a name isn't defined. When Python tries to look-up `hello` inside the body of `func` it will succeed because there's a parameter with that name.

The following works:

```
hello = 'Hello'
def func(hello):
    print(hello)

func(hello)
```

since `hello` will be found when the function call to `func` is made.

Comment: Thank you and yes that makes sense!